# How to generate a dictionary from other two dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

If

`d1 = {'Mercury': 10, 'Venus': 20, 'Earth': 30, 'Mars': 40}`

and

`d2 = {'Ten': 'M', 'Twenty': 'V', 'Thirty': 'E', 'Forty': 'F'}`

then how to generate a new dictionary where the keys belong to d1 and the values belong to d2, similar to the following dictionary:

`newD = {'Mercury': 'M', 'Venus': 'V', 'Earth': 'E', 'Mars': 'F'}`

How to do it through comprehension, loops or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your plan for explaining to Python how to associate `10` to `'Ten'` etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `zip()` method to zip up the keys of `d1` with the values of `d2`:

```
d1 = {'Mercury': 10, 'Venus': 20, 'Earth': 30, 'Mars': 40}
d2 = {'Ten': 'M', 'Twenty': 'V', 'Thirty': 'E', 'Forty': 'F'}

newD = dict(zip(d1,d2.values()))
print(newD)
```

Output:

```
{'Mercury': 'M', 'Venus': 'V', 'Earth': 'E', 'Mars': 'F'}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the association is based on order, you can use `zip`:

```
>>> d1 = {'Mercury': 10, 'Venus': 20, 'Earth': 30, 'Mars': 40}
>>> d2 = {'Ten': 'M', 'Twenty': 'V', 'Thirty': 'E', 'Forty': 'F'}
>>> {k: v for k, v in zip(d1.keys(), d2.values())}
{'Mercury': 'M', 'Venus': 'V', 'Earth': 'E', 'Mars': 'F'}
```

If you want to associate based on `10` -> `'Ten'` etc, `num2words` ought to work:

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> d1 = {'Mercury': 10, 'Venus': 20, 'Earth': 30, 'Mars': 40}
>>> d2 = {'Ten': 'M', 'Twenty': 'V', 'Thirty': 'E', 'Forty': 'F'}
>>> {k: d2[num2words(v).title()] for k, v in d1.items()}
{'Mercury': 'M', 'Venus': 'V', 'Earth': 'E', 'Mars': 'F'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{list(d1.keys())[k]:list(d2.values())[k] for k in range(len( d1.keys()) )}
```